# Using Dir.glob not returning any files in specified directory

Tags: ruby, file, directory, io, glob

I am working on a game and am trying to output the names of save files from  their directory using Dir.glob (if there's a better way to do this, I'm absolutely not attached to that particular function)

I tried using information from various answers on here, but it still isn't outputting any file names to the console.

The file name generator

```
file = File.new("Saves\\" + "#{char.name}" + ".sav", 'w')
```

that's working fine, just wanted to have it in case it has something to do with the file extension.

and the current iteration of the output writer.

```
Dir.glob("/Saves/*") do |file| 
    puts file.basename()
end
```

I'm not sure if it *should* be working per say, but I've tried several different versions that, in theory should be outputting a list.

It outputs a blank line (which also end the program at the moment) even though there are 3 files currently in the directory.

Comment: Try it again but with `"./Saves/*"` or `"Saves/*"`.

Comment: Is there a reason you use a backslash slash in File.new but forward slash in Dir.glob?

Answer (score 0):

per a comment (but not answer) from cremno, changing the "/Saves/*" to simply "Saves/*" fixed it.

Comment: I.suppose technically it’s OK to post this answer, but normally this would simply be a comment on your question, sic: “@cremno, thank you. It works when I remove the first forward slash.”.